# Error when generating allure report with jasmine allure reporter

Tags: allure

I am using jasmine allure reporter. When I ran My test suite got pom.xml generated. But when I wanted to run "mvn site -Dallure.results_pattern=allure-results" command in target directery, getting the following error. Any help highly appreciated.

```
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 ski
n.
[INFO] Generating "Allure" report    --- allure-maven-plugin:2.2
[INFO] Report Version: 1.4.15
[INFO] Results Pattern: allure-results
[INFO] Found [0] results directories by pattern [allure-results]
[INFO] Found [0] plugins
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:44 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-02T17:54:15+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/161M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:si
te (default-site) on project protractor-allure-plugin-generate-html: Error during page generation: Error rendering Maven report: Can't find any results directories by pattern [allure-results] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, pleaseread the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

my pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.yandex.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>protractor-allure-plugin-generate-html</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <allure.version>1.4.15</allure.version>
        <allure.maven.version>2.2</allure.maven.version>
        <!-- Relative to the dir you're running from -->
        <allure.results_pattern>allure-results</allure.results_pattern>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-report-face</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>target/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>2299</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${allure.maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <resultsPattern>${allure.results_pattern}</resultsPattern>
                    <!--<reportVersion>1.4.15</reportVersion>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: It is working fine. I just copied allure-results folder to  node_modules/jasmine_allure_reporter , and ran the command, got the report generated.

Comment: Can you explain the entire path where did you copied the allure-results folder